# Pycharm doesn't save the python interpreter in the configurations

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm, interpreter

Each time if I start the PyCharm after the Laptop restart, the configurations forget the python interpreter. I don't understand how I can save the interpreter for always.

p.s.: PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2

Comment: It might be a silly question, but do you have write-access to the project folder? Or are you working with a temp-folder of some sort? I believe the configurations are saved in a "hidden" _.idea_-folder in each project.

Comment: How are you saving your configuration? Normally, you would have a project default interpreter (in `settings->project->interpreter`), but you can also have a custom interpreter setting in each run configuration.

Comment: @Thomas Fauskanger, hm, It was once a problem with .idea. I use .idea folder from another person, because with my .idea it was impossible to use the debugger...

Comment: Perhaps you can try ``File->Invalidate Caches/Restart ...``, but I'm not sure. 
 What happens if you delete the _.idea_-folder? PyCharm will create a new folder if it's missing, but you might lose some other settings. (Which if I understand you correctly you do on each restart anyway?)

Comment: Also, there is a folder with global settings in _C:\Users\<username>\.PyCharm2017.2_ (at least on Win 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like the problem was that you didn't have write access to your `.idea` folder after copying it from another user.

I'm just copying the comments into an answer so the question doesn't look unanswered anymore.